# How do you use the JSON "can_place_on" tag to specify what kind of blocks (same name, different data value) to place on?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How would you use the `can_place_on` or `can_destroy` tags to specify which data values are valid for the blocks?
Example: I want a diamond block that can be placed on magenta wool only, not any other types of wool. What I've got so far is this:

```
/give @p diamond_block 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["wool"]}}
```

I'm not sure how to specify that the wool needs to be magenta only, which is a data value of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far this is not possible, neither in Java, nor in PE. But for the Java Edition version 1.13 it will, because then the blocks will have names like "magenta_wool". A (probably) complete list of all the block names in 1.13 is here: https://bugs.mojang.com/secure/attachment/141835/the%20flattening.txt

Since it's generally intended by Mojang to have PE and Java at the same state of features soon, it will probably come to PE at some point in the near future, but I can't tell you anything concrete.

Comment: This is pocket edition (as the tag minecraft-pocket-edition says)

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. But after googling a bit it seems to be the same in PE. Just that there's no official announcement for "the flattening" for PE, so I'll change the answer to say that.